# getJSON doesn't work with latest version of jQuery

Tags: jquery, getjson

This following code snippet works fine using jQuery1.2.3, but it doesn’t work with latest version of jQuery:

```
$.getJSON(url,{str: $$.val() }, function(j){
   if (j.length > 0) {
      var options = '<option value="">' +params.firstOption+ '</option>';
      for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
         options += '<option value="' + j[i].optionValue + '">' + j[i].optionDisplay + '</option>';
      }
   }
   $dest.removeAttr('disabled')
        .html(options)
        .find('option:first')
        .attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

Please note that this above code is actually part of a jQuery plugin for cascading drop down list. It produces desired result if I use jQuery1.2.3. The full plugin code is as follows:

```
(function($){

   $.fn.linkedSelect = function(url,destination,params) {


       var params = $.extend({

         firstOption : 'Please Select',

         loadingText : 'Loading...'

      },params);

      var $dest = $(destination);

      return this.each(function(){

         $(this).bind('change', function() {

            var $$ = $(this);

            $dest.attr('disabled','false')
                 .append('<option value="">' +params.loadingText+ '</option>')
                 .ajaxStart(function(){

                    $$.show();

            });

            $.getJSON(url,{str: $$.val() }, function(j){
               alert('User clicked on this.'); 
               if (j.length > 0) {

                  var options = '<option value="">' +params.firstOption+ '</option>';

                  for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {

                     options += '<option value="' + j[i].optionValue + '">' + j[i].optionDisplay + '</option>';

                  }

               }

               $dest.removeAttr('disabled')
                    .html(options)
                    .find('option:first')
                    .attr('selected', 'selected');

            }); // end getJSON

         });  // end change

      }); // end return each

   };  // end function

})(jQuery);
```

Please note that it can't generate the following alert message

```
alert('User clicked on this.');
```

what is written inside the getJSON function for debugging purpose  if I use latest version of jQuery. And I have also traced using JS debugger, it can't step into the getJSON function if I use latest version of jQuery. But, it shows this alert message if I use jQuery1.2.3.

In error console, warning messages are:

```
Warning: reference to undefined property b.p.height
Source File: http://localhost//js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js Line: 99
Warning: reference to undefined property b.p.serializeGridData
Source File: http://localhost/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js Line: 62
Warning: reference to undefined property jQuery.event.triggered
Source File: http://localhost/js/jquery1.7.js Line: 2924
Warning: reference to undefined property elem[jQuery.expando]
Source File: http://localhost/js/jquery1.7.js Line: 1719
```

What should I change to adapt with latest version of jQuery. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! "It doesn't work" is *never* a good error description. Please describe what goes wrong, what error messages you get, etc.

Comment: so where exactly is the failure? you can add some console.log to the code to find out and exactly what is the latest version of jquery you are trying to use and how did you load it?

Comment: Could you explain more in depth how it isn't working and what your test case is?  You are testing the exact same inputs on the exact same code, and the only difference is the jQuery version, right?

Comment: @Andrew Latham, If I use jQuery1.2.3, I get desired results.

Comment: @Pekka, I've edited this question to describe well so far. Does it make sense about the problem now?

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense now. I agree with Matt - it looks like you need to update jqGrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your server is producing invalid JSON.

Comment: Thank you all for quick reply. @blockhead, I've tested. It produces valid JSON.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Actually, jQuery 1.3 and earlier used JavaScript’s eval to evaluate incoming JSON. jQuery 1.4 uses the native JSON parser if available. It also validates incoming JSON for validity, so malformed JSON (for instance {foo: "bar"}) will be rejected by jQuery in jQuery.getJSON and when specifying “json” as the dataType of an Ajax request.

Comment: My server side script would produce the JSON like { Value: 28.000, Display: "28.000"} and would work fine with jQuery1.3+. For latest jQuery, I have to change it as { "Value": "28.000","Display":"28.000"}

Comment: @wachy: Thank you! You helped me out. I was missing the double-quotes around my values and I couldn't figure out what the problem was.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the errors in the console, it looks like the version of jqGrid you're using is not compatible with jQuery 1.7.

If it's the same jqGrid version that you were using with jQuery 1.2.3, well, that's not surprising in the least. [jQuery 1.2.3](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.2.3.js) is ancient history — released almost four years ago.

Comment: I've updated jqGrid and its jQuery version exactly according to the documentation. Please note there is no problem in jqGrid functionality, but problem in Cascading (Linkedselect) plugin. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, then it could very well be that other plugin. To start, you should be using [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop) instead of `.attr()` for disabling `$dest`.

Comment: I've tested the cascading plugin without jqGrid plugin in separate file. It generate same problem with jQuery1.5.2 in cascading functionality, but no problem with jQuery1.2.3. So, problem is only in Cascading plugin. What better cascading plugin do you advise to use instead? I also used .prop() instead of .attr() for disabling $dest for testing purpose.

Comment: I don't have a particular plugin I use for this purpose, so I can't recommend one beyond google.